# Are cycles in computing equal to time?

Tags: performance, time, cpu, hardware, cycle

I have a book describing energy saving compiler algorithms with a variable having "cycles" as measuring unit for the "distance" until something happens (an HDD is put into idle mode).

But the results for efficiency of the algorithm have just "time" on one axis of a diagram, not "cycles". So is it safe to assume (i.e. my understanding of the cycle concept) that unless something like dynamic frequency scaling is used, cycles are equal to real physical time (seconds for example)?

Comment: Only if the book is old or if it doesn't mind intentionally ignoring what real processors look like today.  They dynamically adjust their clock frequency.  Either because the chip is getting hot (turbo boost) or to save battery life when operating without AC.

Comment: the book is about high performance computing which is sort of a special case and it does describe the algorithm and possible savings in an abstract way; without actually measured, only estimated data

Comment: Be careful though, if some operation takes 8,000,000 cycles but is spread efficiently across 8 cores, it may only take 1,000,000 cycles of real world time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cycles are equal to real physical time, for example a CPU with a 1 GHz frequency executes 1,000,000,000 cycles per second which is the same as 1 over 1,000,000,000 seconds per cycle or, in a other words a cycle per nanosecond. In the case of dynamic frequency that would change according to the change in frequency at any particular time.